# Why is Silver Fang rated as S-class Rank 3 hero?

Tags: one-punch-man

It's clearly that there is bunch of heroes are more powerfull but for some reason ranked below. *Zombieman, Flashy Flash, Child Emperor* - all of the guys allready beaten monsters ranked above **Demon** level, while *Bang* along with his brother *Bomb* couldn't handle exausted *Garou*.

Is the ranking system not reliable source for heroes strength comparison or Bang just still didn't show all of his abilities?

Comment: Bang finished 2 dragon level threats who also were executives of the monster association, supposedly among the strongest dragon level threat monsters there are. And if I recall correctly he defeated them with only one punch, theorically stronger than those dragon level threats defeated by Zombieman, Flashy Flash and Child Emperor

Comment: "Bang finished 2 dragon level threats who also were executives of the monster association" are you refering to some recent manga chapters?

Comment: no, to the webcomic

Comment: which one? can you provide me link?

Comment: @gokareless Chapter 72 of the webcomic is where it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an addition to Pablo's answer:

The following page appears in Chapter 72 of the webcomic (text spoilers after):

> [image: Blast explains Bang's lethality]

> Just before Bang basically one-shots multiple Dragon level threats in a row (he also takes out a whole bunch of Black Sperms in a flash), Bomb informs Genos that the reason Bang brought him (Bomb) along to deal with Garou was so that he (Bang) wouldn't accidentally kill Garou.  He was not there because Bang was not strong enough to deal with Garou, but because Bang was too strong and has problems not killing things when he's actually going all-out.

Comment: Did you mean Bomb? Bang's brother's name is Bomb, Blast is the #1 hero of the hero association

Comment: Ironically in the chapter of Bomb's first appearence, Bomb thinks for himself that Bang called him because he was worried of Garou's power. I guess the author forgot about what he wrote or he just retconned it later and wanted to make Bang look stronger than he did before

Comment: @Pablo He could simply be worried that Garou has become powerful enough that Bang would have to fight seriously enough to risk killing Garou despite his desire to not do so.

Comment: Bang is insane @@

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers from the webcomic

> In the webcomic he defeats Fuhrer Ugly and Gums , who are dragon level threat and executives of the monster association, supposedly executives of the monsters association are stronger dragon level threat monsters than the dragon level threat monsters Child Emperor, Zombieman and Flashy Flash have killed.

So in the anime and in the manga he hasnt shown everything he can do compared to the webcomic.